# Alternative option to create ZIP files using SAS ODS PACKAGE

Tags: sas, zip

In the past I used ODS PACKAGE in a 5.1 EG environmment to create zip files and I worked find. I'm now working in a different environmment  and it seems winzip is not installed on the SAS server. Does anyone knows If there an alternative to this code?

```
`/* Creating a ZIP file with ODS PACKAGE */
ods package(newzip) open nopf;
ods package(newzip) add file=newcsv path="data/";
ods package(newzip) add file=rm;
ods package(newzip) publish archive 
  properties(
   archive_name="carstats.zip" 
   archive_path="&projectDir."
  );
ods package(newzip) close;`
```

Thanks

Comment: What version of SAS are you using? Not the EG version, but the version of SAS that EG is calling.  Newer versions of SAS include the ZIP filename engine.

Comment: fyi, you will get the info that @Tom requests by submitting %put MySASversion=&sysver;

Comment: @Tom SAS version is 9.3

Comment: I think you need 9.4 to use the ZIP engine on a FILENAME statement.  WINZIP is a Windows package. Is your SAS server running on Windows?  Perhaps you can ask SAS support what is needed to support package generation.